# Search and replace only part of the text using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following content in a file.

```
$ cat file.txt
path,foo,12344,bar,foo,example4/path/1,test2
path,bar,12345,bar,bar,example2/path/4,test5
```

I would like to change the "path" on the 6th field to "test-path".

```
path,foo,12344,bar,foo,example4/test-path/1,test2
path,bar,12345,bar,bar,example2/test-path/4,test5
```

I tried with following, but it didn't work.

```
$ awk -F, -v needle='path' -v replacement='test-path' 'BEGIN{ OFS = FS; } (NR > 1 && $6 == needle) { $6 = replacement; } 1' file.txt
```

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv Thanks for pointing out, I will add the filename.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv because there is an occurrence of the same string in 1st column, and I don't want to change that. I just want to change the 6th column content.

Comment: Or you can assign  full path instead of partial to variable.

Comment: @steeldriver I thought the same, I was not sure which one would do the regex part, thanks for pointing out ~, I will try the same.

Comment: @steeldriver Unfortunately ~ didn't work. It is clear that I have to use regex to replace the part of the string in a column, but not sure about the exact way.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood what you are trying to do (it would have been helpful if you'd been more specific than "didn't work")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '{gsub("path","test-path",$6)}1' file.txt

path,foo,12344,bar,foo,example4/test-path/1,test2
path,bar,12345,bar,bar,example2/test-path/4,test5
```

To substitute `path` with `test-path` only in 6th field

Answer (score -1):

Tried with below command

```
$ sed "s/\/path/\/test-path/" filename
path,foo,12344,bar,foo,example4/test-path/1,test2
path,bar,12345,bar,bar,example2/test-path/4,test
```

Comment: The risk here is that the sed command you've used would replace any and all "/path" strings to "/test-path" -- and not just the ones in field 6, as required.